# Angular 9 call function when two components loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, dom-events

I am trying to have two components, `<app-map>` and `<app-markers-list>`.

`<app-map>` loads Google Maps API and displays a map on the page. It emits a `mapLoaded` event in `ngAfterViewInit()`

`@Output() mapLoaded: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();`

`<app-markers-list>` loads a list of markers via Angular's `HttpClient`. It emits a `markersLoaded` event at the end of `HttpClient.get().subscribe()` Observable.

`@Output() markersLoaded: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();`

How do I catch these two events at once so I can call another component's function that will populate the map with the markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a simple solution.

```
@Output()
allLoaded = new EventEmitter();

oneLoaded = false;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.emitAllLoaded();
}

yourFunctionWhereHttpClientGetLocated() {
   this.http.get(..).subscribe(() => {
       this.emitAllLoaded();
   });
}

emitAllLoaded() {
   if (oneLoaded) this.allLoaded.emit();
   oneLoaded = true;
}
```

You might don't need to use Observable or Subject

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to capture events from `<app-map>` and `<app-markers-list>` in a parent component. 
You can capture as we generally do, put binding in parent template as below:

```
<app-map (mapLoaded)="mapLoaded($event)"></app-map>
<app-markers-list (markersLoaded)="markersLoaded($event)"></app-markers-list>
```

Now you can manage these events in parent component. You can use subjects or observables and observable operators (combineLatest, of). Please find the code below how you can use it.

```
import { combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';

    // this will be your parent component.
    export class ParentComponent {

      mapLoaded = new Subject()
      mapLoaded$ = this.mapLoaded.asObservable();
      markerListLoaded = new Subject()
      markerListLoaded$ = this.markerListLoaded.asObservable();

      constructor() {
        const combinedValues = combineLatest(mapLoaded$, markerListLoaded$);
        combinedValues.subscribe((value) => {
          // Here you can write code when you receive notification from both the events.
        })
      }

      mapLoaded(mapLoadedData) {
        this.mapLoaded$.next('map loaded successfully');
      }

      markersLoaded(markersLoadedData) {
        this.markerListLoaded$.next('markers loaded successfully');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that ```combineLatest()``` is deprecated so I had to use the solution from Robert B. below.

Comment: No problem, we can use zip as well.